# O que fazer quando a resposta escolhida é a menos recomendada?

Tags: debate, respostas

Respostas escolhidas geralmente são as primeiras que são seguidas por outros usuários, por estarem no topo, mas e quando as mesmas não são claras o suficiente, ou fogem do escopo da pergunta, não há nada ser feito? percebi isso nessa questão [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241080/formatar-campo-de-busca-com-bot%C3%A3o-css/241096#241096)

Comment: Eu quase faço esse questionamento desse post [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240579/64969). Na hora, o AP selecionou a minha resposta como aceita, mas a resposta do Maniero estava muito superior a minha. Antes que eu tomasse qualquer decisão, o AP mudou a resposta aceita para a do Maniero, então não tomei ação alguma

Comment: Aconteceu hoje o [mesmo comigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241091/3635).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Isto vive acontecendo e de fato as pessoas tendem a olhar só para a aceita e até mesmo votar nela, mesmo quando ela está errada.

Não tem muito o que fazer. Pode comentar pedindo para melhorar a resposta, como pode fazer em qualquer resposta, aceita ou não. Se feito de forma educada, com o intuito de melhorar a qualidade do conteúdo do site eu acho saudável. EU sei que tem gente que não acha. Há uma corrente de pessoas que acha que o melhor é ficar quieto e deixar tudo como está.

Pode comentar com o AP para ele rever sua aceitação. Mas é preciso fazer com cuidado para não parecer "puxar a sardinha" demais para o seu lado, não parecer que ele é obrigado mudar algo. Ele muda se quiser. Tente mostrar porque há algum problema ali com o melhor que puder argumentar. Mas deixe pra lá se ele não quiser mudar.

Se a resposta está claramente errada pode negativar também, afinal ela está aceita e causando confusão. Só não vá negativar porque está concorrendo com a sua e não quer ver ela se destacando. Eventualmente pode sinalizar como baixa qualidade.

Se todas estiverem certas e o AP escolheu uma que você acha que não é ideal, sendo a sua ou de outro melhor, é uma prerrogativa dele escolher o que quiser, e pense também que você pode estar enganado e, pelo menos para aquele caso, a aceita pode ser a melhor para o AP, ainda que você não concorde.

Não tenho conhecimento e não gastei tempo suficiente para falar sobre o caso específico.

Comment: Eu ia responder, mas esta resposta já cobriu os pontos de que eu ia tratar. Sobre as respostas em questão, tanto a aceita quanto a do Felipe e a outra têm o mesmo problema: não explicam a solução, apenas entregam o código. Então, Felipe, você pode aproveitar para tentar melhorar a sua resposta. Certamente isso atrairia alguns votos.

Comment: É verdade, existe nas duas.

Comment: @bfavaretto, realmente, não costumo fazer isso, mas já editei a resposta para referências futuras, em relação a concorrência de respostas, também concordo, acredito que outro exemplo ilustraria melhor essa questão, porém o contexto é compreensível.

Answer (score 8):

Complementando a resposta do Maniero, é necessário entender o porquê disso acontecer também.

Já vi acontecer algumas vezes onde o AP aceita a resposta que é a mais fácil dele copiar-e-colar no seu sistema, mesmo que seja uma gambiarra horrorosa e cheia de problemas.

Também já vi casos onde o AP aceita apenas a resposta que concorda com a linha de pensamento que ele já tinha e mantém o *status quo*, rechaçando respostas que proponham a ele uma alternativa melhor ao mudar algumas coisas.

Outro motivo que leva a isso, é quando o AP aceita a primeira resposta que funcionar para ele, e não a melhor alternativa a funcionar. Muitas vezes ele nem se dá ao trabalho de ler as demais respostas.

Frequentemente, as melhores soluções são mais difíceis de entender, e o AP pode ser um dos que não entendem.

Por vezes, o AP não tem tempo/vontade/paciência de ler as respostas, então ele vai olhar preferencialmente para as menores respostas.

Ou seja, o que ocorre é que a maioria dos respondentes espera que a melhor resposta seja aceita, mas nem sempre o AP se importa com a qualidade das respostas recebidas ou mesmo sabe como julgá-las.