# E se a resposta for muito boa... em mostrar como NÃO fazer?

Tags: debate

No site, sempre buscamos àquelas respostas que respondem muito bem o que foi perguntado, mas o que fazer com  aquelas respostas que mostram exatamente o oposto: "o que **não** **deve** ser feito naquele contexto"?

É comum em algumas respostas lermos coisas como "todo mundo faz assim, mas está errado...", até mesmo já presenciei acontecendo da pessoa responder com tal solução pois aprendeu daquela forma e achar que é a melhor, mas não é. Na minha opinião, uma resposta que mostra o como **não fazer** também é uma resposta válida e bem-vinda no site, desde que deixado, de alguma forma, explícito que a solução, mesmo que "resolva" o problema, não deve ser seguido.

A questão levantada aqui é justamente essa: como podemos, como comunidade, deixar explícito que a resposta é ruim?

A solução mais direta é negativar, porém, visto que o autor perde reputação para cada voto negativo que recebe, na minha opinião, acredito que isso acaba sendo um incentivo para ele remover a resposta. Removendo a resposta, ela acaba ficando visível apenas para usuários com uma determinado mínimo de reputação e usuários novos não terão o "privilégio" de ver o como não fazer, abrindo uma brecha, inclusive, para outro usuário responder a mesma coisa.

- [O que se fazer com respostas que tem problemas de segurança?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6244/5878)
- [O que fazer quando a resposta escolhida é a menos recomendada?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6384/5878)
- [Como comentar perguntas/respostas ruins da forma correta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5814/5878)

É fácil perceber que se ainda não existe uma outra resposta que deixe explícito qual é a melhor maneira de se resolver o problema, deixando claro as falhas da resposta ruim (se ela mesma não deixa claro isso), essa resposta deve ser criada, mas como deixar explícito na resposta ruim que ela não deve ser utilizada sem incentivar a exclusão da mesma?

**Obs.:** isso é diferente de manter qualquer besteira como resposta. Se é visto que a resposta não agrega em nada, ela deve ser removida. A questão seria manter apenas aquelas respostas em que a solução é ruim, mas sabemos que muita gente usa sem saber que é ruim.

Comment: Algo discutido em meios não oficiais ([Telegram](https://t.me/joinchat/Hv4yERLcVDESTcbrT_BsnA)) seria de converter a resposta para wiki, de forma que o autor não perdesse a reputação com votos negativos e, assim, não se sentir "pressionado" em remover a resposta.

Comment: Eu penso que se a solução é ruim, a resposta deve sim ser negativada até que seja corrigida ou apagada. Agora, explicar que é ruim é totalmente diferente. Não acho que deve ser mantido, por mais que o "ruim" seja um indicativo de como não fazer, acho que poderiam criar uma resposta wiki explicando, primeiramente, porque aquela solução é ruim, como algumas respostas que temos no site.

Comment: É bom ficarmos atentos também aos efeitos colaterais dessa sugestão, pois ela pode abrir brecha a quem não quer perder reputação, mesmo com uma resposta errada, e começarem a criar tudo como wiki.

Comment: Com certeza, @articuno, mas acho que criar tudo como Wiki não será exatamente um problema, pois o usuário também abriria mão de ganhar a reputação com a resposta. E se a resposta for realmente ruim, pode ser corda para ser removida sendo wiki ou não.

Comment: Isso já acontece bastante: **"abrindo uma brecha, inclusive, para outro usuário responder a mesma coisa."**

Answer (score 11):

Creio que apesar de termos vários casos, ainda podem ser considerados exceções. Em vários comentários anteriores eu já sugeri nunca votar pra remover "resposta ruim exemplo", só negativar, pelos motivos expostos na questão. Agora que o assunto foi trazido à tona, pensei um pouco melhor e cheguei nesta...

### Proposta

- Copiar a solução da resposta ruim em uma nova resposta, prefixando com um aviso do tipo:

  ***"Uma das respostas propôs esta solução, mas ela tem problemas:"***

  deixando bem claro que não é para usar aquilo.
- Dissecar as linhas ou o conceito problemático, explicando detalhadamente a razão daquilo não ser bom, com o máximo de referências possíveis, e de preferência do próprio SOpt;
- Colocar a solução correta, ou caso já tenham se esgotado as possibilidades, referenciar as outras respostas boas, se possível explicando como elas solucionam o problema.
- No caso de a solução já estar nos outros posts, e a resposta nova só abarcar a errada, iniciar a resposta com um título "Resposta complementar", para que se evitem enganos de negativação indevida ou flags de não é "resposta", e tomar um cuidado maior com a linha que explica que aquilo foi postado para corrigir um conceito errado anterior.

Desta maneira, a resposta ruim "original" pode seguir seu ciclo normal sem dano aos futuros visitantes, independente de continuar a ser negativada, removida pela comunidade ou pelo autor, ou simplesmente deixada lá.